# CartoDB infowindows - only show title if data exists?

Tags: carto, infowindow

I have a data set in which not all tuples have info for all columns.

I want to show those columns in the infowindow, but if the data value is inconsequential (doesn't exist, is zero in a field where zero equates to doesn't exist), I don't want the title of the field shown - absence should be sufficient to show the user that the data isn't there.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [mustache templates](https://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html). In the [custom HTML infowindow](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-editor.html#on-click-info-windows) field (or hovers), you can put the following around text you want to conditionally appear:

```
{{#col_name}}
<p>{{col_name}}</p>
{{/col_name}}
{{^col_name}}
<p>No information</p>
{{/col_name}}
```