# Displaying link title instead of URL in Infowindow of CartoDB?

Tags: carto, infowindow

In my data, I have a column containing some url values; where the url is unavailable, it contains the text value "Not yet available".

I want the output in the map infowindow to either display, "Not yet available" in cases where there is no url or "Link to website," where you can click through to the url.

I played with both the sql and html to try to make this happened, but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the conditional Mustache templates in order to achieve this, I recommend you to take a look at the solution [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151743/cartodb-infowindows-only-show-title-if-data-exists).