# Null vs. blank in click vs. hover info window in CartoDB?

Tags: carto, infowindow

I've noticed that in my CartoDB info windows, if a given column does not have a value for a point, that lack of value shows up as a blank in the hover window, but it shows up as a null in the click window. Is CartoDB set up so that this intentionally happens? Is there a way to change this setting?

Edit: I also am working on a project with over a dozen columns, any of which could potentially be blank at a given time, so to go in and change the HTML for each one of them, although doable, is rather tedious.

Comment: This was answered in the following QA: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151743/cartodb-infowindows-only-show-title-if-data-exists

Comment: I had seen that QA before, and it was definitely very helpful to me. It just seemed odd to me that the default was null for the click and blank for the hover, so I wanted to see if there was an answer from that perspective. Thanks!